# What were the acts of the first human between the Svāyambhuva Manvantara and Vaivasvata Manvantara. (Manvantaras 2-6) What do other humans do then?

Tags: puranas, gods, time, human, manu

In the long period of not hearing about the first human a lot, he was born by the names Svārociṣa, Uttama, Tāmasa, Raivata, and Cākṣuṣa. What was that Sāvarṇi up to during those times? How did his natures of being Sarvavarṇyantaka manifest back then as it would later on with the events in the Kali Yuga prophecies? Also, where are all the other humans? Are there any stories involving humans before the flood story in Vaivasvata Manvantara?

Do humans appear other than those names listed above in Manvantaras 2-6?

Comment: Voting to close as you are only allowed to ask one q.

Comment: @Wikash_  It effectively is one question. What do humans do in manvantaras 2-6